# How do I subtract time from now() in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to post the now() time to mysql (doing this from php) minus one second (or minute). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select now() - interval 1 second
```

or use [DATESUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
select DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 second)
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3611)

Comment: I may not have been clear enough: I need to insert that value into the database. DO I do that the same way?

Comment: yes. example: `insert into your_table (date_column) values (now() - interval 1 second) `

Answer (score 0):

If you require formatting to your date, you could use,

```
select TIME_FORMAT(now() - interval 1 second,'%H:%i:%s')
```

There are lots of websites showing this info too. [Source](http://www.eltcalendar.com/stuff/datemysqlphp.html)